# Trying to import a third party library in Javascript - getting a 404

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, asp.net-core, wwwroot

I have the a library referenced in my Asp.Net Core lib folder, under:

```
wwwroot/lib/vendor/product/dist/browser/library.js
```

I'm referencing that from my own JS module like this:

```
import { library } from '../lib/vendor/product/dist/browser/library';
```

The console error message tells me that this can't be found:

```
https://localhost:12345/lib/vendor/product/dist/browser/library (404)
```

When I look in sources, I can't find the library either - so it makes sense.  My question is: why is this library not included in the sources?  My understanding was that Visual Studio would do a local deploy, and anything inside wwwroot would get deployed to the local server; however, I assume this isn't happening, and that's why I'm getting the error.

As an aside, the library wasn't imported using npm, but copied manually into the lib folder; however, I've checked inside and outside VS, and the files are where they are supposed to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from your sample, the **js** extension is ommited. That might be the cause

Comment: You were correct - although I would have solved this myself if I was able to see the source in the F12 tools.  I'm still unclear as to why they were not there.